# Tough problem of circle and rectangle

Tags: circles, area

A rectangle is overlapping the circle. The centre of the rectangle and circle are the same point. The two sides of the rectangle is tangent to the circle. The dimension of the rectangle are 6 by 12. The sides 6 are both tangent to the circle.

> How do I find the area of the intersected part comprise of the circle and rectangle.

Try: The diagonal of the rectangle we can use Pythagoras theorem

Let d be the diagonal of the rectangle,

$d=\sqrt{6^2+12^2}=6\sqrt{5}$

So the radius, r, of the circle is $r=3\sqrt{5}$

I can only find parts of the areas. The rest it is quite difficult to tackle.

Comment: if both short sides are tangent to the circle then circle diameter should be $12$

Comment: small sides 6 are tangent not the big side

Comment: exactly. try to draw a picture

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The radius of the circle is $6$.

Let $ABCD$ be the rectangle with $AD=BC=6$ and $AB=CD=12$. Let $O$ be their common centre.

Suppose that the circle cuts $AB$ at $E$ and $F$ such that $E$ is closer to $A$ than $B$. Also, suppose that the circle cuts $CD$ at $G$ and $H$ such that $H$ is closer to $D$ than $C$.

We have $OE=OH=EH=6$. So $\angle EOH=60^\circ$. The area of sector $OEH$ is $\pi (6^2)\div 6=6\pi$. The area of sector $OFG$ is the same.

The area of $\triangle OEF$ is $\frac{1}{2}(6)^2\sin 120^\circ=9\sqrt{3}$. So is the area of $OGH$.

The area of the required region is $2(6\pi+9\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: If the circle touches both shorter sides of the rectangle, the chord joining the two points of contact is a diameter, which has a length $12$.

Comment: the rectangle touches the circle with it both side of 6 vertically and 12 is horizontally

Comment: @GiantLeap Which figure?

Comment: here is a picture https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+with+rectangle&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo6fy00Z7aAhWCKsAKHUzZDFoQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=651#imgrc=EcZh5LtEr51l-M:

Comment: but the small is tangent to the circle.

Comment: @GiantLeap Please see my edited solution. Is that the figure?

Comment: yessss that is the picture. thank you @CY Aries

Comment: @GiantLeap Can you see that the diameter has the same length as $AB$?

Comment: yes I see, thank you